# android - How can I send the value of my spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am having a hard time sending the value of my spinner to my web server. I have some text areas and a spinner on my form. I can get the values of the textareas, post the to my server and save them to a database. But I can not seem to find a way to do this with the spinners.

Can anyone help?

MainActivity.java:

```
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                               adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



    etPostCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPostCode);
    etAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress1);
    etRecordNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRecordNum);
    etContainerType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContainerType);
    etContainerSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContainerSize);
    etContainerSerial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContainerSerial);

}

public void signup(View v) {
    String postCode = etPostCode.getText().toString();
    String address1 = etAddress1.getText().toString();
    String recordNum = etRecordNum.getText().toString();
    String containerType = etContainerType.getText().toString();
    String containerSize = etContainerSize.getText().toString();
    String containerSerial = etContainerSerial.getText().toString();


    Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Record...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new SignupActivity(this).execute(postCode, address1, recordNum, containerType, containerSize, containerSerial);
}
```

My Spinner in conent_main.xml:

```
    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I have tried to use String spinner = Spinner.getSelectedItem().toSting();

But I get the error:

Non-static method 'getSelectedItem()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: your Spinner variable is called spinner, not Spinner. String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toSting()

Comment: String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 2):

Try to add listener at your spinner:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mSelectedItemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String spinner = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
};
```

And set the listener at your spinner:

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mSelectedItemListener);
```